# HCatOutputFormat ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hcatalog

I Have a mapreduce program in which i make use of Hcatalog to get details from a Hive table 'A' with HcatInputFormat, process it and write it back to Hive table 'B' using HcatOutput format.

i wrote the program using eclipse and created a runnable 'Hadooptest' jar from the project, and i run the jar using hadoop jar command in hadoop cluster (with -libjars parameter

when i create runnable jar by extracting all referenced jar into the jar file, and then execute in hadoop cluster, the mapreduce runs fine and finishes successfully.

The issue is, when i create runnable jar using the 'copy required libraries into sub-folder next to generated JAR' option, then move both the jar and refrenced libraries to hadoop cluster, and execute it, It shows

> "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found"

below is the full yarn log :

```
2016-06-29 12:17:57,951 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Created MRAppMaster for application appattempt_1466834505106_0057_000002
2016-06-29 12:17:58,672 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-06-29 12:17:58,773 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Executing with tokens:
2016-06-29 12:17:58,773 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Kind: YARN_AM_RM_TOKEN, Service: , Ident: (appAttemptId { application_id { id: 57 cluster_timestamp: 1466834505106 } attemptId: 2 } keyId: 783034855)
2016-06-29 12:17:58,974 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Using mapred newApiCommitter.
2016-06-29 12:17:59,840 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: OutputCommitter set in config null
2016-06-29 12:17:59,920 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:472)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1496)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getOutputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$1.call(MRAppMaster.java:468)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
        ... 13 more
End of LogType:syslog
```

And it is necessary that i export required libraries into seperate folder and not extract into the jar itself.

Any help to figure this out will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All the jars aalready exists in your hadoop cluster, you need just to pass their location to your program, it's mentioned in the official [doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+InputOutput#HCatalogInputOutput-RunningMapReducewithHCatalog) :

```
export HADOOP_HOME=<path_to_hadoop_install>
export HCAT_HOME=<path_to_hcat_install>
export HIVE_HOME=<path_to_hive_install>
export LIB_JARS=$HCAT_HOME/share/hcatalog/hcatalog-core-0.5.0.jar,
$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-metastore-0.10.0.jar,
$HIVE_HOME/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar,
$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-exec-0.10.0.jar,
$HIVE_HOME/lib/libfb303-0.7.0.jar,
$HIVE_HOME/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar,
$HIVE_HOME/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HCAT_HOME/share/hcatalog/hcatalog-core-0.5.0.jar:
$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-metastore-0.10.0.jar:
$HIVE_HOME/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar:
$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-exec-0.10.0.jar:
$HIVE_HOME/lib/libfb303-0.7.0.jar:
$HIVE_HOME/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar:
$HIVE_HOME/conf:$HADOOP_HOME/conf:
$HIVE_HOME/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop --config $HADOOP_HOME/conf jar <path_to_jar>
<main_class> -libjars $LIB_JARS <program_arguments>
```

Comment: Yeah @54l3d ..i am doing exactly this... I have mentioned in a line above...i am using -libjars to pass along the $LIB_JARS parameter, and i am also setting the HADOOP_CLASSPATH env variable... But still **HcatOutputFormat ClassNotFoundException"**